# Fixnum doesn't have an "induced_from" method on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

What to use as an alternative?

My code..

```
time = Fixnum.induced_from(minutes_past)
```

This works on my local but not on my remote Heroku.

Heroku doesn't have this method as a listed method for Fixnums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this method is deprecated in ruby 1.9.x and last existing version where you can you it is 1.8.7. I believe that is a source of your problem.
There are a couple of methods for converting value as instance of Numeric class to value as instance of Fixnum class in 1.9. For example:

```
1.0.to_i      # => 1
1.to_i        # => 1
```

or

```
Integer(1.0)  # => 1
Integer(1)    # => 1
```